# Xtend lambda expression overloading for Xtext QuickFix API

Tags: java, eclipse, lambda, xtext, xtend

I am using Xtend to write custom QuickFixes for the Eclipse UI plugin of my Xtext language. The idea is to extend `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.DefaultQuickfixProvider` and use call the `accept` method of an `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.quickfix.IssueResolutionAcceptor`.

`accept` has several overloaded signatures, including:

- `void accept(Issue issue, String label, String description, String image, IModification modification)`
- `void accept(Issue issue, String label, String description, String image, ISemanticModification semanticModification)`

Using the first of those signatures is easy using Xtend's lambda expression syntax:

```scala
@Fix(MyDSLValidator::INVALID_TYPE_NAME)
def removeInitialUnderscore(Issue issue, IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
    acceptor.accept(issue,
    "Remove initial underscore",
    "Remove initial underscore",
    'upcase.png')
    [
        context |
        context.xtextDocument.replace(issue.offset, 1, "")
    ]
}
```

The Xtend compiler produces the following Java code:

```java
public void removeInitialUnderscore(final Issue issue, final IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
  final IModification _function = new IModification() {
    public void apply(final IModificationContext context) throws Exception {
      IXtextDocument _xtextDocument = context.getXtextDocument();
      Integer _offset = issue.getOffset();
      _xtextDocument.replace((_offset).intValue(), 1, "");
    }
  };
  acceptor.accept(issue, 
    "Remove initial underscore", 
    "Remove initial underscore", 
    "upcase.png", _function);
}
```

Now I want to write a second QuickFix that uses `ISemanticModification` instead of `IModification` so that I can get access to the underlying EMF model, not just the strings. However, I'm struggling to tell the Xtend compiler which overloading of the method I'd like to use:

```scala
@Fix(MyDSLValidator::MISSING_USAGE)
def addMissingUseStatement(Issue issue, IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
    acceptor.accept(issue,
    "Add missing use statement",
    "Add missing use statement",
    "upcase.png",
    [
        EObject element |
        (element.eContainer as MyContainer).usages.add(
                    (element as MyElement).myattr.eContainer as MyOtherContainer
                )
    ])
}
```

Xtend always thinks I want to pass an `IModification` instead of an `ISemanticModification` and produces an error in the compiled java code because the two `apply` methods have different signatures, `IModification` takes an `IModificationContext` while `ISemanticModification` takes an `EObject`.

```java
@Fix(MyDSLValidator.MISSING_USAGE)
public void addMissingUseStatement(final Issue issue, final IssueResolutionAcceptor acceptor) {
  final IModification _function = new IModification() {
    public void apply(final IModificationContext element) throws Exception {
      EObject _eContainer = element.eContainer(); // COMPILE ERROR
      EList<Circuit> _usages = ((MyContainer) _eContainer).getUsages();
      MyAttr _myattr = ((MyAttr ) element).getMyattr();
      EObject _eContainer_1 = _myattr.eContainer();
      _usages.add(
        ((MyOtherContainer) _eContainer_1));
    }
  };
  acceptor.accept(issue, 
    "Add missing use statement", 
    "Add missing use statement", 
    "upcase.png", _function);
}
```

How do I tell Xtend which overloading to use? As far as I know, it's not possible to create an anonymous object in Xtend, so there needs to be another way to call `IssueResolutionAcceptor.accept` passing an `ISemanticModification`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISemanticModification accepts two arguments where the IModification only uses one argument. To implement a semantic modification, you should use a lambda with two parameters respectively:

```
acceptor.accept(issue,
    "Add missing use statement",
    "Add missing use statement",
    "upcase.png") [ element, context |
      ..
    ]
```